# Facebook SDK issue with login

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, sdk

Using the Hackbook Facebook code I have a problem with the screen just after the user logs in to Facebook.  Right after the user logs in s/he gets the same pre-login screen.  When the login button is pressed, s/he get to the correct (showLoggedIn) screen.  See below is the code that is used, but I have yet to figure out the changes necessary.

Is there any way in which there is a break in the code to login to Facebook and then after the login sequence (through a browser) to continue to the next sequence (showLoggedIn)?  Thank you.

```
- (void)login {
    HackbookAppDelegate *delegate = (HackbookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (![[delegate facebook] isSessionValid]) {
        [[delegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
    } else {
        [self showLoggedIn];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Todd

```
- (void)login {

// Check and retrieve authorization information
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    facebook.sessionDelegate = self;
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_likes", 
                            @"read_stream",
                            //@"user_about_me",
                            //@"email",
                            //@"publish_stream",
                            @"publish_actions", 
                            @"offline_access",
                            nil];
    [facebook authorize:permissions];
    //  [permissions release];
} else {
    [self showLoggedIn];
}
}
```

i am using ARC thats why i have commented permission release, i hope this serves what you needed

Comment: Hi, I do not think that will work for me as it just checks and retrieves authorization information.  When I plugged it into the code, I got the same thing...I have to press the login button again to get in.  Thank you.